# Obj is not pushing into array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach, push

Here i am receiving a set of token in csv texts and every token belongs a document in monogdb. My logic is to get the documents token wise and return them as an array to the front end .

Here I have done this but its returning an empty error instead of array of objects.

```
var helps = [];
        const token_list = req.body.token_list;
        let splittedtoken = token_list.split(",");
        splittedtoken.shift();
        console.log(splittedtoken);
        splittedtoken.forEach(token => {
            Help.find({ 'token': token }, (err, result) => {
                if (result) {
                    helps.push(result[0])
                }
            });
            console.log(helps);
        })`
```

i am unable to solve it , any kind suggestions are heartly welcome . Thanks

Comment: `Help` is your db collection. It's async but `forEach` is not async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databse operations are async but `forEach` is not.

You can use `Promise.all` to achieve it. First, push all db operations to an array and then use `Promise.all` to retrieve it's results.

```
var helps = [];
const token_list = req.body.token_list;
let splittedtoken = token_list.split(",");
splittedtoken.shift();
console.log(splittedtoken);

let promises = [];

splittedtoken.forEach(token => {

  promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => Help.find({
    'token': token
  }, (err, result) => {
    if (result) {
      resolve(result[0])
    }
  })));

});

Promise.all(promises).then(results => console.log(results)).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Do note that, Promise.all is all or nothing. If a single promise was rejected, the entire operation will fail and catch block will execute.